# How can I match a tag ignoring its attributes

Tags: regex

So say I have some HTML that looks like the following

```
<a href="#">This text</a>
<a href="#" target="">This Text</a>
<a href="#" oncick="" target="">This Text</a>
```

What regex would grab 'this text'? I'm really new to the concept of regex so have tried things like "(.*)" but not really had much success. Can anyone offer advice? :D

Comment: In the right hands, regular expressions are a very powerful and useful tool. However, using them safely and effectively (even for seemingly simply tasks) requires a rather in-depth knowledge of how the underlying engine performs its pattern matching. Like a handgun, regexes must be treated with a lot of respect - its _very_ easy to shoot yourself in the foot! In particular, beware the (overused) _dot-star_ (i.e. `.*`) hammer! [Garvin's excellent reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is a good place to start. Happy regexing!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following regular expression

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

You can find more examples on [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) site

Comment: Same ignoring namespace prefix : 
<\b[^>]*:a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\b[^>]*:a>